# Append function is doing nothing on a custom JQuery function

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm Trying to create a function on JQuery to make something simple... add elements on a . This is the code but it's not working

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.dataProvider = function (array) {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(array);
        $.each(array, function (index, value) {
            $(this[0]).append("<option value = '" + index + "' >" + value + "</option>");
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But this works!

```
$.each(array, function (index, value) {
    $(this[0]).append("<option value = '" + index + "' >" + value + "</option>");
});
```

I can't understand why... can anybody help me?

Comment: check your firebug first what is the error

Comment: It's not giving me errors, just the append() function is doing nothing

Comment: A new function creates a new scope, even the callback for $.each()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a plugin, you need to return `this` element in order to maintain chainability:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ABUSoPOy/3/edit)

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.dataProvider = function(arr) {

    var that = this;
    var opts = ""; 

    return that.each(function(){
       for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         opts += "<option value='"+ i +"'>"+ arr[i] +"</option>";
       }
       that.append( opts ); // Append only once // Faster!
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Example of plugin chainability:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bee"];
$('#sel').dataProvider( arr ).css({color:"red"});
```